# How to detect changes in the value of an input text, when the value is modified by another event

Tags: jquery

I'm wondering how to detect changes in the value of an input text, when the value is modified by another event.

```js
$('input').on('change', function() {
  //I expected this below to be shown when pressing '+'
 alert("You changed the value of the input");   
})

$('span').on('click', function() {
    $('input').val('1');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input  type="text" value="0">
<span>+</span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [JQuery onChange documentation](https://api.jquery.com/change/) (equivalent to on('change', ...)):

> Note: Changing the value of an input element using JavaScript, using
>   .val() for example, won't fire the event.

However, you can trigger a change event yourself after updating the field:

```
$('span').on('click', function() {
    $('input').val('1').change();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

It may seem dirty, but you could just set up an interval to check the value.

```
var inputValue = $('input').val();
setInterval(function () {
    if($('input').val() != inputValue) {
        alert("Changed");
    }
},100);
```

The only other option you have is to move the `alert` event into the method that is causing the value change, in this case the click on the plus.